# Toggle Responsive CSS Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in my script I am working on I have MANY various options the user can set VIA variables. Now one of my variables is cfs_responsive and I have a JavaScript if condition checking for true/false or 1/2 values as well as if the actual variable is set. Now where I am stuck is here. Once I get the condition written correctly how am I supposed to turn on and off the responsive css code?

My responsive css code is the following.

```
/* ===RESPONSIVE=== */
    /* CSS DIRECTORY
        1. =primaryCATEGORY
        2. =subCATEGORY
        3. =lowerCONTENT
    */
    @media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
        /* ===primaryCATEGORY=== */
            /* Single Primary Category Divider */
            .cfs_primaryCategory {
                margin-left: 0px;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .cfs_primaryCategory h1 {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            .cfs_primaryCategory.cfs_primaryCategory-active h1 {
                visibility: visible;
            }
            .cfs_primaryCategory.cfs_primaryCategory-active {position: relative;z-index: 999;}
        /* ===subCATEGORY=== */
            /* Single Sub Category Divider */
            .cfs_subCategory {
                margin-left: 0px;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .cfs_subCategory.cfs_subCategory-active {position: relative;z-index: 999;}
        /* ===lowerCONTENT=== */
            /* Lower Content Wrapper */
            .cfs_lowerContent-wrapper {
                padding: 25px 35px 0px 35px;
                max-width: 450px;
            }
    }
```

Would the only way of doing this be seperating the stylesheet into two different stylesheets then having the js within the if statement include the stylesheet if true?

I would really Like to keep the stylesheet all together.

Let me know what you think.

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: The specific sections of responsive code is "turned on and off" by the width of the screen. There is no javascript (or jquery) involved. The answer is to change the width of your browser. Either you've misunderstood responsive CSS or I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: You mis understood me... The options in the script allow to turn on or off the responsive mode. Therefore disabling the responsive part of the script.

Comment: Ok. Your idea to keep it as a separate stylesheet and add/remove it from the page is sound. The only other option I can think of is to add/remove a class on body, i.e. `<body class="responsive">` and use that in the CSS `body.responsive .cfs_primaryCategory {...}`.

Comment: Perfect idea! Didnt even think about that... or since my script has a wrapper cfs_wrapper I can just edit the responsive code  for .cfs_wrapper.cfs_responsive ... {....] and have the js add the extra responsive class!

Comment: Huge Thanks, if you want to put that comment as a answer than I will pick you as best answer! thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to keep it as a separate stylesheet and add/remove it from the page is sound.

The only other option I can think of is to add/remove a class on body or another parent element, e.g. `<body class="responsive">` and use that in the CSS:

```
body.responsive .cfs_primaryCategory {...}
```

JQ

```
$('body').toggleClass('responsive');
// or $('body').addClass('responsive');
// and $('body').removeClass('responsive');
```